# R - Basic String Manipulation

Tags: r, string, replace

I am currently working with Amazon.com product review & sales rank data in R. I have little experience with string manipulation so I'd like your help.

Consider the following column (below) that stores a product 'Sales Ranking' in a string.
A product can be ranked in multiple rankings within an individual string. E.g. a headphone can be ranked in both the  category 'On-ear Headphones, as well as in the category 'Cell Phones & Accessories'. As seen below, within the string, the different rankings are split up by a ";".

Please note that the column below only displays the string of the first row (df$rank[1]), and that df$rank[2] would be found at the "..."

```
df$rank <- c(">#316,475 in Cell Phones & Accessories ;>#1,908 in Cell
 Phones & Accessories > Cell Phone Accessories > Headphones > On-Ear 
Headphones;>#3,410 in Cell Phones & Accessories > Cell Phone 
Accessories > Headphones > Over-Ear Headphones;>#52,046 in Electronics
 > Portable Audio & Video > MP3 & MP4 Player Accessories", "...")
```

How do I manipulate the string so that:

1. I select the right ranking out of the string (upon my decision)
2. I only end up with the relevant ranking integer from said ranking.

In other words:
How do I go from the example string mentioned above, to the integer value below, given that I want to end up with the number 1,908?

`df$rank <- c( 1,908 ; ...)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please use valid R syntax for your sample data? Your string has no quotes, making it invalid and also impossible to tell if it's a single big string or a vector of strings (and if a vector, where do the elements start and end?).

Comment: If you have the data in `df$rank`, then `dput(df$rank[1:3])` will create copy/pasteable output to create the first 3 items in valid R syntax.

Comment: @GregorThomas My bad. I added the quotes so that it now should be clear where the first string starts and ends.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the below steps.

```
rank <- c(">#316,475 in Cell Phones & Accessories ;>#1,908 in Cell
 Phones & Accessories > Cell Phone Accessories > Headphones > On-Ear 
Headphones;>#3,410 in Cell Phones & Accessories > Cell Phone 
Accessories > Headphones > Over-Ear Headphones;>#52,046 in Electronics
 > Portable Audio & Video > MP3 & MP4 Player Accessories")

split_rank <- strsplit(rank, ";")[[1]] # split the strings per ;
all_spaces_indices <- gregexpr(' ', split_rank) #retrieve indices where the string is a space
first_spaces_indices <- sapply(all_spaces_indices, function(x) x[1]) # keep only the first space
mynumber_raw <- substr(split_rank, start=3, stop=first_spaces_indices) # substring between 3 and the first space
mynumber <- as.numeric(gsub(',','',mynumber_raw)) #remove commas and convert to numeric


#now you can do the filtering
split_rank[mynumber==1908]
[1] ">#1,908 in Cell\n Phones & Accessories > Cell Phone Accessories > Headphones > On-Ear \nHeadphones"
```